# install4j + add action/condtion to check if browser is open

Tags: browser, install4j

In an install4j generated installer, I want to check if the browser is open before proceeding with the further steps of installation. How can I get it done? Checked with all the available actions of install4j and didn't find anything. I am using install4j version 4.2, hence will not be able to check with the active processes running on the system.

Answer (score 0):

install4j 4.2 does not have the required functionality. You need install4j 6 where you can use the `com.install4j.api.windows.WinProcesses` API to find out if a particular application is running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any work around? I will not be able to upgrade to the higher version.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this with install4j 4. The feature was not yet implemented.